# Max number in array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, for-loop

I know many solutions exist for this one, but after looking around I haven't found any that involves pointers

Right now it keep throwing warnings and there's no output at all, what am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int findbig (int a[], int n)
{
    int max = a[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] > max)
        {
            max = a[i];
        }
    }

    return max;
}



int main (void)
{

int n;

printf("How many numbers? \n");
scanf("%d", &n);

int a[n];

printf("Now enter those %d numbers: \n", n);

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }

int biggest = findbig (a[n], n);

printf("The biggest number is: %d\n", biggest);

return 0;
}
```

My compiler is complaining that:

> -warning: passing argument 1 of 'findbig' makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
>
> -note: expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int'

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)` --> `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a[n]` (as well as its equivalent `*(a + n)` form) is an int, not a pointer to int.  It's also one past the boundary of your array.  You need to turn your warnings into errors. You pass an int, whose *value* is converted to a pointer (address), which is, well, no good.

You need to call your function like so:

```
findbig(a, n);
```

Regardless of your signature, `findbig` receives a pointer to int.  You cannot pass arrays to (or return them from) functions in C.  They degrade to pointers to their first element.

---

On a side note, you're always skipping the first element when populating the array, so the user says "I want to enter N numbers", but you only allow them to enter `n-1`.  The is also problematic as you use `a[0]` as your initial `max` number, but the value of that element is indeterminate.

It could be anything, i.e., some huge number, and then your function will give strange results.  Either initialize the array to 0 (`int a[n] = {0};`) or start your loop at 0 (better).

Comment: I tried fixing that, but now it gives me random gibberish which I assume is the address of the value. I tried to dereference it but with no avail:                                                     How many numbers?
5
Now enter those 5 numbers:
1
6
2
3
1
The biggest number is: 2686652

Comment: @user3109599: No, the problem is how you are populating the array (not populating the first element).  I edited my response with that info right as you were leaving your comment.

Answer (score 0):

By indexing `a`, doing `a[n]`, you get the value of the array a in the n-th index, which is of int `type`. You need to invoke `findbig(....);` function using the array "pointer" variable, without indexing it, by doing:

```
findbig(a, n);
```

Answer (score -2):

This line is wrong.

```
int a[n]
```

Array should be initialized with constant value, because the space of array is allocated before execution of the program. So, variables won't work.

Comment: Wrong. C99 allows for VLA's (variable length arrays) and, if that were the problem, his program would not even compile.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, but I can't compile it on my VS because of this problem.

Comment: Because VS is outdated (C89, some more C99 stuff in 2013).  You're using a very old C compiler (or a C++ compiler which will not allow VLA's).